# How to convert array from single array to multidimensional array on php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array from excel file like this.

```php
   $array = [
     ['parent 1', '10000', '20000'],
     ['parent 1', '15000', '21000'],
     ['parent 2', '13000', '22000'],
     ['parent 2', '11000', '5000'],
   ];
```

How to convert array above with php to array like this below

```php
   $array = [
     'parent 1' => [
        ['10000', '20000'],
        ['15000', '21000']
     ],
     'parent 2' => [
        ['13000', '22000'],
        ['11000', '5000']
     ]
   ];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through array to make first value as key and rest its values.

**Version 1**

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $result[$v[0]][] = [ // making first value as key and reset its values
        $v[1], $v[2],
    ];
}
print_r($result);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99400734cc368136c53c1938e19febb7ddfe145b).

**EDIT**

**Version 2**

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $result[array_shift($v)][] = $v;
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [parent 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10000
                    [1] => 20000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15000
                    [1] => 21000
                )

        )

    [parent 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13000
                    [1] => 22000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11000
                    [1] => 5000
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple and precise solution.

```
$array = [
   ['parent 1', '10000', '20000'],
   ['parent 1', '15000', '21000'],
   ['parent 2', '13000', '22000'],
   ['parent 2', '11000', '5000'],
 ];

$output = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $output[$value[0]][] = array($value[1],$value[2]);
}
print_r($output);
```

The `parent 1` and `parent 2` lie on the `0` index and other entities lie on the `1` and `2` indexes. I have assigned `1` and `2` index values to `0` index in a new array while each iteration

**OUTPUT**

```
    Array
(
    [parent 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10000
                    [1] => 20000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15000
                    [1] => 21000
                )

        )

    [parent 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13000
                    [1] => 22000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11000
                    [1] => 5000
                )

        )

)
```

Here is the [demo](https://3v4l.org/Wkkel)

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: How it wrong? can you please explain it more. Thanks

Comment: Look precisely to the expected array OP wants, deeply sharply. You will get it, or else, compare with my output and check whether you get your flaws. But if you will make answer like mine, your answer will have no value ;)

Comment: @RahulMeshram Yes you were right. I have updated my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

Demo: https://3v4l.org/XoivL

```php
   $array = [
     ['parent 1', '10000', '20000'],
     ['parent 1', '15000', '21000'],
     ['parent 2', '13000', '22000'],
     ['parent 2', '11000', '5000'],
   ];


    $new_array = array();

    foreach($array as $a) {
       $temp = array_slice($a, 1);

      if(!array_key_exists($a[0], $new_array)) {
          $new_array[$a[0]] = array();
      }

       array_push($new_array[$a[0]], $temp);

    }

    print_r($new_array)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
[parent 1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10000
                [1] => 20000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 15000
                [1] => 21000
            )

    )

[parent 2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 13000
                [1] => 22000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 11000
                [1] => 5000
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sorry for that! I have updated my answer.

Comment: Your update doesn't explain what you did. Imagine you are having to teach a new programmer what to do. What would you tell him/her?